# Why don't user authentication plugins use the DBMS "user table" instead of creating their own?

Tags: authentication, database

Is it because of portability? I think that it'd be better if they did, permission and group management would be safer in my opinion.

What I generally saw and did was to create a user account in the DBMS for the system, store that user name and password in a configuration file and accessed the database through it. The authentication module/plugin [always!] works independently the DBMS's user table.

Is there a reason for it?

Am I doing it wrong? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the reason is that if the plugin did that, then the user would be able to get access to your table using the user credentials, which is gigantic potential security hole. You want to give the user access to your app, not to the system running the app.

Comment: When you say that "the user would be able to get access to your table using the user credentials", to which table do you refer? the DBMS's user table or the plugin's user table?